# jupyter lab open an iframe on a tab for monitoring dask scheduler

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, dask, dask-distributed, jupyter-lab

I am developping with dask distributed and this package provides a very useful debugging view as a bokeh application.

I want to have this application next to my notebook in a jupyterlab tab.

I have managed to do so by opening the jupyter lab reference (Help > Jupyter lab reference) and modifying the url with the inspect tool of firefox from it's orignial value to 127.0.0.1:8787 (the URL for the dask dashboard)

see below :

[dask scheduler console in jupyter lab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iMMG.jpg)

Is there a less hacky way to open a website in jupyter lab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is an active Github issue for this.  I recommend tracking https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/2369

It sounds like you may also want to look at https://github.com/dask/dask-labextension